# Modifying data in a Backbone Collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a backbone collection coming in that has multiple attributes in each collection. One of these attributes is a wait time and is coming in only as minutes. I would like to convert this to hours and minutes so the users don't have to convert the value in their head.

I have the code to convert it, but I seem to be having trouble grabbing that value from the collection.

I have already tried parsing the data into JSON like so

```
JSON.parse(this.app.workflow.get('WaitList'))['time']
```

or like this

```
kb.collectionObservable(JSON.parse(this.app.workflow.get('WaitList')))['time']
```

or this

```
 ko.observable(JSON.parse(this.app.workflow.get('WaitList')))['time']
```

or just plain

```
this.app.workflow.get('WaitList')['time']
```

but nothing seems to work.

One of the attribute nodes looks like this

```
\attributes: ObjectActivityId: 57DisplayName: "NAM, N": 15Time: 136GroupIndicator: ""LocationId: 0Name: "NAME, NAME"Order: 1
```

from my model I have

```
this.set('WaitList', new Backbone.Collection());
var _this = this;

            $.getJSON('file', function(data){               
                _this.get('WaitList').add(data.WaitList);
                return data;
            });
```

Comment: when you say collection there are many models with time you want to convert data in all models are particular model?

Comment: There are many models inside the collection and each of the have the attribute of time that I wish to convert.

Answer (score 0):

```
  this.app.workflow.get('WaitList').each(function(model){
  //assume the attribute name is minutes
  var minutes = model.get('minutes');

  // your logic for conversion goes here 
  var result = toHours(minutes);  

  model.set({'Hours':result});
});
```

now you have the model with both the minutes and hours data

Comment: I am confused... How do I call the right collection? this.collection could be any collection I have going on and I have a few...

Comment: what is the name of the collection that have the models?

Comment: I'm just grabbing it by calling this.app.workflow.get('WaitList')

Comment: var someThing = new Backbone.Collection.extend({}); you must have written some thing like that and something is the collection here,else post the complete code

Comment: In mY Model I'm creating the backbone collection (this.set('WaitList', new Backbone.Collection());) and setting JSON variables to it, but I am not extending it. I am trying to handle this from my view model though where I am grabbing the collection that was already created.

Comment: @zazvorniki check now

Comment: I'm not even getting a console.log within the each statement. What is the model you are passing in? Is that the model in the view? The minutes is actually in the collection not yet in the model...

Comment: When I say console.log I mean something like this...not connected to the data console.log('here');